# x509 certificate error when creating Docker manifest

Tags: docker

I'm trying to create a multi-arch manifest with Docker, but I'm seeing the following error:

```
failed to configure transport: error pinging v2 registry: 
Get "https://myregistry:5000/v2/": x509: certificate relies on legacy Common Name field, use SANs instead
```

I've added `myregistry` to the `insecure-registries` of my Docker configuration and I can pull and push images to/from that registry.

The command I'm trying is:

```
docker manifest create myregistry:5000/new-image:latest --amend myregistry:5000/new-image-amd64:latest --amend myregistry:5000/new-image-arm64:latest
```

I will need to start a (probably) lengthy process with another team in order to have them update the certificate. So I'm wondering if I can work around this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the issue. When creating/pushing a manifest, the flag I had to add was `--insecure`.

The full command is:

```
docker manifest create myregistry:5000/new-image:latest --amend myregistry:5000/new-image-amd64:latest --amend myregistry:5000/new-image-arm64:latest --insecure
```